# How to check if the parent node is body node?

Tags: javascript, html

If I want to test if an element is on the body node is checking the nodeName property accurate enough?

```
if (element.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()==="body") {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Compare the references:

```
element.parentNode === document.body
```